# manipulation of list of lists

Tags: prolog

I am having a list of lists and I am trying to access each inner list and check the elements contained within and then create a list with some numbers according to the elements i already found. for example if I have a list of lists like [[w,w,w,c,w],[w,l,r,w,w]]. i should go over the elements in each list and if all the elements are "w"s then my output list should add a (0), if it contains a "c" it should add a (1), and a (2) for the elements l and r and so the result in this case should be [1,2].
Now my problem is with the base case I am using in my helper predicate check_rows1\2. I added several base cases but they are not working properly.

check_rows([],*,*,Totals). 
         check_rows(L,W,H,Totals):-
           list_to_llists(L,W,LL),
           check_rows1(LL,Totals).

```
     check_rows1([],Totals).
     check_rows1([[]|T2],Totals):-
     check_rows1(T2,Totals).
     check_rows1([[H1|T1]|T2],Totals):-
       H1=c,
       append(Totals,1,O),
       check_rows1(T1,O).

     check_rows1([[H1|T1]|T2],Totals):-
       H1=w,
       append(Totals,0,O),
       check_rows1(T1,O).

     check_rows1([[H1|T1]|T2],Totals):-
       H1=l,
       append(Totals,2,O),
       check_rows1(T1,O).
```

Comment: Why do you tag this with Haskell?

Comment: I edited that tag out.  If anything Haskell-ish appears in the question then the tag can be added at that time.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm working on several projects different languages. Any suggestions for the problem??